# Get filepath/name of a File Descriptor in node.js

Tags: node.js

How do you get fullpath **from a file descriptor** in node?

```
var fs = require('fs')
var fd = fs.openSync('package.json', 'r')

console.log(fd) // 10

console.log(get_file_path_from_fd(fd)) // HELP
```

Edit: I have found [this](https://coderwall.com/p/llunqa/get-path-of-a-file-descriptor-in-linux-in-node-js)

```
> fs.openSync('.', 'r')
10
> fs.readlinkSync('/proc/self/fd/10')
'/home/alfred/repos/test
```

but i didn't find proc folder in Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { execSync } from 'node:child_process'
import { pid } from 'node:process'
import fs from 'node:fs'

const fd = fs.openSync('package.json', 'r')
const fullpath = execSync(`lsof -a -p ${pid} -d ${fd}`).toString().split('\n')[1].split(/\s+/).pop()

console.log(fullpath) // result: /fullpath/package.json
```

Comment: This is great. But it will fail if the path contains spaces. Rather than ending with `.split(/\s+/).pop()`, instead use `.slice(56)`. Or put a `-Fn` in the invocation of `lsof` and then end with `.slice(1)`.

Comment: On *nix (with `/proc`), one could use one of the `readlink's`, - `readlink('/proc/self/fd/' + fd)` –

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you're loading a file that is in the same directory as the script, you could just use the `__dirname` global to find the current directory.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

In fact, I prefer to load files using `__dirname` as part of the path for the `fs` module as a good practice. For example, this is from a Discord bot I have...

```
var tokenJSON = require( __dirname + '/json/discord_token.json');
```

Edit: So to put this into the answer itself; your `fd` variable contains the *data* that was loaded from the file, but it is completely disconnected from the file it came from originally. If you are being given an arbitrary file to load and you would like to have the path, we need to know more about how that file is being provided to you. When the file is given to you there should be a path included (so the script can locate the data!) and that is what you want. If there is no path like in your example, then that means the relative paths are the same and it's the current directory.

Comment: I got nothing against using `__dirname` either but i can get a unknown `fd` from somewhere and i want to know where the file path is

Comment: Well your problem is that `fd` is the contents of the file, not the file's path. You don't have a variable storing the file's path. You could add one, but right now all you're doing is telling `fs` to load the contents of the file and store it into `fd`. The data is completely disassociated from the original file at that point.